# Proper way to implement user input with Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am currently working on creating a python script that will do a series of calculations based on the formula entered by the user; however, it is not working as expected?

I have tried the following:

```
init_printing(use_unicode=True)

x, y = symbols('x y', real = True)
userinput = sympify(input("testinput: "))

x_diff = diff(userinput, x)

print(x_diff)
```

However, this always returns zero, but when I write the input directly, e.g.

```
init_printing(use_unicode=True)

x, y = symbols('x y', real = True)
userinput = x**0.5+y

x_diff = diff(userinput, x)

print(x_diff)
```

It works flawlessly, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `locals` parameter in `sympify` function will help you. Here is a working code, based on yours :

```py
from sympy import *

init_printing(use_unicode=True)

x, y = symbols('x y', real = True)
userinput = input("testinput: ")
locals = {'x':x, 'y':y}
sympified = sympify(userinput, locals=locals)
print(f'derivate /x : = \n {diff(sympified, x)} \n derivative / y : \n {diff(sympified, y)}')
```

Output:

```
testinput: cos(y) + 2*x

derivate /x :
2
derivative /y :
-sin(y)
```

Comment: Found in the doc (https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html) : *In order to have strings be recognized it can be imported into a namespace dictionary and passed as locals*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have found the docs to be quite hard to understand. I now see how it works.